# How to call javascript method on button click after the form inputs have been validated

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ASP.NET MVC web page which is essentially a form to fill in and select certain fields. I am using twitter bootstrap as well.

My.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyWork";
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/mywork.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/typeahead.min.js")
}

<br />

<legend>Add items to enable work</legend>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        Item name:
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="ItemTextBox" name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter an item name ..." class="form-control" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
    </div>
</div>

<legend>Generate file</legend>
<input id="GenerateFile" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate File" onclick="javascript:generateFile()" />
```

The javascript file mywork.js contains the generateFile() method and creates a file using the items entered.

How should I validate that the ItemTextBox is not empty? There can be a number of items added so I obviously don't want to check for each text element. I have set the required="required" for the inputs. How can I auto-validate the required fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any plug-in, for browser's default validation,
wrap your input elements with `<form></form>`. And add `"required"` attribute to all required input fields.

```
<form id="myform">
     <p><span>Item 1</span> <input name="Item 1" type="text" placeholder="Enter an item name"required="required" autofocus="autofocus" /></p>
     <p><span>Item 2</span> <input name="Item 2" type="text" placeholder="Enter an item name"required="required" autofocus="autofocus" /></p>
     <p><span>Item 3</span> <input name="Item 3" type="text" placeholder="Enter an item name"required="required" autofocus="autofocus" /></p>
     <p><input type="submit" value="Generate File"/></p>
</form>
```

Call generateFile function when form get submitted (your form won't get submitted until all required fields are filled) and prevent browser from submitting form to server.

```
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function(e) {
    generateFile();
    e.preventDefault();
}
function generateFile(){
    alert('Generating File');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ajeeshms/gJncc/)**

Comment: I have not defined my elements inside a form. If I define a form then how to one call the javascript method on click without making a round trip to the server (i.e. I don't want to do a POST).

Comment: I went with this approach, it works. I had to change legends to h1 since legend doesn't work inside form. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this link might help you:

[Jquery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

As you have added a "required" attribute, you can just validate a form and then call your javascript method using the above plugin:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // some other code
    // maybe disabling submit button
    // then:
    $(form).submit();
  }
 });
```

Comment: I have not defined my elements inside a form. If I define a form then how to one call the javascript method on click without making a round trip to the server (i.e. I don't want to do a POST).

Answer (score 0):

did you tried jQuery validation engine, its a nice and best plugin to validate your form controls very easily. Just have a look at below link (its a demo)

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

To download and for documentation visit

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Comment: Does this work without defining form element in my .cshtml. I couldn't figure out how to work with it for client side validation.

Comment: @AloofC Yes, you can validate by control, just refer above sites. Do you need any demo for validating controls?